# TLP is not running on system startup after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04+

Tags: power-management, tlp

TLP configurations is not applied on system startup after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.04. Reinstalling the package does not help.

Inspecting TLP systemd unit `tlp.service` confirms the issue.

```
$ systemctl status tlp.service                  

● tlp.service - TLP system startup/shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tlp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: https://linrunner.de/tlp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The new power-profiles-daemon package is the problem** (see [TLP/issues/564](https://github.com/linrunner/TLP/issues/564)). This package is installed by default in Ubuntu 21.04+ and a couple of other distributions.

#### Explanation

The new power-profiles-daemon package comes with a systemd unit `power-profiles-daemon.service`. This unit declare a conflict with `tlp.service` causing `tlp.service` to be effectively disabled.

/lib/systemd/system/power-profiles-daemon.service (notice the `Conflicts=` directive)

```
[Unit]
Description=Power Profiles daemon
Conflicts=tuned.service tlp.service auto-cpufreq.service
Before=multi-user.target display-manager.target

...
```

If a unit has a `Conflicts=` directive on another unit, starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa. And because `tlp.service` doesn't declare `Conflicts=` directive on `power-profiles-daemon.service`. It will always be the one that get disabled regardless of the activation order of the units.

#### Solution

- You may either disable power-profiles-daemon.service unit with `sudo systemctl disable power-profiles-daemon.service`; or
- Remove power-profiles-daemon package from the system with `sudo apt purge power-profiles-daemon`.
- Alternatively, you may override `tlp.service` configurations with `sudo systemctl edit tlp.service` and set the the `Conflicts=` along with `Before=` directives manually.

```
[Unit]
Conflicts=power-profiles-daemon.service
Before=power-profiles-daemon.service
```